# telegram channel's post view count

Tags: api, telegram

I want to learn more about telegram channel's post view count system. How does it work ? and what are the API (in VB) parts involved regarding to this.

Comment: what exactly do you wish to achieve?

Comment: increasing post view count

Answer (score 18):

I had this question too. To get the answer I created a private channel and added one of my friends to it and posted some text.
So only 2 people were in the channel and as the channel was private no one else had the chance of visiting the channel. After some days I understood that posts' view count increases and after searching a lot I understood that **telegram counts view times when a specific user sees the post and this is repeated every 24 hours.**

> For example if you view a post today at 8:00 pm, other views will not
> count until tomorrow 8:00 pm and this cycle continues.

**Update:** After reading Krishnakanth Allika's comment, I decided to update my answer in order to help those who are visiting this page a long time after the date the post was published. Telegram mentions [in this](https://telegram.org/faq_channels#q-what-does-the-eye-icon-mean) link that these stats are reset about every 4 days which is a more up-to-date information.

Comment: I didn't know this

Comment: @THEGREY Me too, and I almost found nothing about it on the net. So I decided to test it my self. It's something like youtube's videos' view count every time you play it, the count increases but in Telegram it happens every 24 hour.

Comment: you can contact me : t.me/code4343

Comment: Here's a link to Telegram's FAQ on this topic: https://telegram.org/faq_channels#q-what-does-the-eye-icon-mean 
Telegram forgets every 4 days and counts as a new view even if it's the same user visiting after that period.

Comment: @KrishnakanthAllika Telegram's algorithm used to forget these records every 24 hours by the time I posted this answer. It might have updated this feature. Thanks for your comment. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have this number from Telegram Bot, but you can get from post-link.
For example link to post https://t.me/losslesmusic/443

[image: Photo]

The counter is this:

```
> <span class="tgme_widget_message_views">55</span><span
> class="copyonly"> views</span><span
> class="tgme_widget_message_meta"><a class="tgme_widget_message_date"
> href="https://t.me/losslesmusic/443"><time
> datetime="2018-02-26T19:14:11+00:00">Feb 26 at 21:14</time></a></span>
```